# Generated constructors if class has a member with same name as class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I had a class with a `std::vector` member that had the same name as the class and had no user-defined constructors; later I had a factory method that generated one of these objects:

```
#include <vector>

class data {
    std::vector<int> data;
};

data create()
{
    data d{};
    // ...
    return d;
}
```

When I try to build this with Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.19), it fails to compile with:

```
    error C2664: 'data::data(data &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>' to 'const data &'
    note: Reason: cannot convert from 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>' to 'const data'
    note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
    note: This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'data::data(data &&)'
```

On Compiler Explorer, this code also failed on MSVC 2019, but *does* compile in GCC 10.2.  So is this a bug in MSVC, is it not standard compliant code, or is this behaviour "implementation dependent"?

Both MSVC and GCC give clear errors that a class with *user-declared* constructors can't have a member of the same name, but what if the class just has compiler generated constructors?  And what about declaring constructors as either `default` or `delete`, does that still count as user-declared?

BTW, I notice that the behaviour of MSVC was different if I changed the type of the member from `std::vector`, so this definition did compile:

```
class data {
    int data;
};
```

And likewise if the factory just returned an rvalue rather than a local, MSVC again did compile it:

```
data create() { return {}; }
```

Comment: Looks like a MSVC bug to me. Rather strange bug though :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard [class.mem#21](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem#21)

> if class T has a user-declared constructor, every non-static data member of class T shall have a name different from T.

So your code above is valid, and the compiler must accept it. This bug is fixed in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/generated-constructors-if-class-has-a-member-with/1626621

> what about declaring constructors as either `default` or `delete`, does that still count as user-declared?

Yes, these are also considered as user-declared constructors.